# Single product page doesn't display price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following code to display price once entering single product page.

```
 <?php 
   global $woocommerce;
   $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); 
   echo $product->get_price_html(); //Shows the price
 ?>
```

I have tried serval variation of this code, but they all either error or empty value.

Although `<?php echo get_the_title() ?>` does work.

What can be causing `get_price_html()` to echo empty value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the product's ID you can use that to create a product object:

```
$product= wc_get_product( $product_id );
```

Then from the object you can run any of WooCommerce's product methods.

```
$product->get_regular_price();
$product->get_sale_price();
$product->get_price();
```